# C# : Can I simplify the generics here

Tags: c#

I have this class that's meant to represent a binary expression. The immediate improvement I'd like to make is to not have to declare the intermediate type of the operands; when declaring the expression, I'd like only to have to give it an input and an output. But output type of the 2 operands must match for compatibility sake. Let me demonstrate:

```csharp
            var gt = new GreaterThanOperator();
            var input = new BookingState();
            var left = new ConstantOperand<BookingState,double>(10d);
            var right = new ConstantOperand<BookingState,double>(20d);
            var leftExpression = new Expression<BookingState, double, bool>(left, gt, right);
```

I would ideally like to reduce the code to be more inline with:

```csharp
            var gt = new GreaterThanOperator();
            var input = new BookingState();
// remove 'double' because it's redundant with the constructor param
            var left = new ConstantOperand<BookingState>(10d); 
            var right = new ConstantOperand<BookingState>(20d);
// remove 'double' because it's derived from operand, and 'bool' because it's derived from the 
// operator return type
            var leftExpression = new Expression<BookingState>(left, gt, right);
```

I think, but I am not sure (and hence why I am here), that I could get there with the usage of factory methods (since I will want all expressions unique and shared as they are stateless; however, that's for another post)

```csharp
    public class Expression<T,M,TOutput> : AbstractOperand<T,TOutput>
    {
        private readonly IOperand<T, M> left;
        private readonly IOperator<M, TOutput> op;
        private readonly IOperand<T, M> right;

        public Expression(IOperand<T, M> left, IOperator<M, TOutput> op, IOperand<T, M> right): base(input => op.Apply(left.GetValue(input), right.GetValue(input)))
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.op = op;
            this.right = right;
        }
        public TOutput Evaluate(T input) => base.GetValue(input);

        public override string ToString() => $"({left} {op} {right})";

    }
```

IOperand

```
    public interface IOperand<T,TResult> : IEquatable<IOperand<T,TResult>>
    {
        int Id { get; }

        TResult GetValue(T input);
    }
```

IOperator

```
  public interface IOperator<in T, out TResult>
    {
        int Id { get; }


        ISet<string> Registrations { get; }

        TResult Apply(T left, T right);

    }
```

AbstractOperator

```
    public abstract class AbstractOperator<T, TOutput> : IOperator<T, TOutput>
    {
        private static int idCounter = 0;
        private readonly Func<T,T, TOutput> f;

        public AbstractOperator(ISet<string> registrations,Func<T,T, TOutput> f)
        {
            this.Id = idCounter++;
            this.f = f;
            this.Registrations = registrations;
        }

        public int Id { 
            get; 
            private set; 
        }
        public ISet<string> Registrations { 
            get; 
            private set; 
        }

        public TOutput Apply(T left, T right) => f(left,right);
    }
```

LogicalOperator

```
    public abstract class LogicalOperator<T> : AbstractOperator<T,bool>
    {
        public LogicalOperator(ISet<string> registrations, Func<T, T, bool> f) : base(registrations, f) { }
    }
```

GreaterThanOperator

```
    public class GreaterThanOperator : LogicalOperator<double>
    {
        public GreaterThanOperator() : base(registrations,(left, right) => left > right) { }

        private static ISet<string> registrations = new HashSet<String>{"gt", ">"};

        public override string ToString() => ">";
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have since updated it to use factory methods and it doesn't help (or at least I can't figure out how):

```
var rightExpression = Expression<BookingState, double, bool>.GetInstance(left, gt, right, "50 is greater than Foo.Bar");
```

It's *more* verbose now

Comment: Is having them as non static classes required? Cause as you mentioned the only way to make this work is with the builder pattern. Kinda like `var left = BookingState.ApplyOperand(ConstantOperand, 20d)`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking so - I started implementing something similar. But, I wasn't sure.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).